# I don't have a startup folder

Tags: windows-10, boot, shell, start-menu

I'm trying to make a file startup every time I turn my computer on, but I don't have a startup folder, I did Win + R and then typed in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, but get this error:
[image: Windows Cannot find]

Then I tried to type into run `shell.startup` and I get this error:
[image: Can't find shell:startup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"*  (as you posted in your question) is the Startup location for All Users.

If you did not have the folder, it just means you have no startup items for All Users.

But if you wish your app to start for All Users, this is where it would go, and you can make the Startup folder for your item. The folder exists (empty) on an older ThinkPad of mine running Windows Insider. The All Users programs were uninstalled.

Further information from:  [All Users Startup](https://www.maketecheasier.com/find-windows10-startup-folder/)

> You can manually add program shortcuts here, and they’ll start up with
> your PC from now on, but apps that have been automatically added by
> third-party software or Windows 10 are controlled from the Task
> Manager

.

Comment: So I tried that path and it gave me the same error but when I check task manager and then startup it shows several programs when I run it as administrator, am I missing something? I thought you could put a shortcut in the startup folder and it would startup on boot and show up in task manager.

Comment: It may be how the app is behaving.  It needs to offer the ability to (a) start for All Users or (b) start for the current user. If the app will set it up, the ProgramData folder is the location for it.

Comment: You can use the folder in ProgramData .... Startup and it should work. But to show up in Task Manager requires the app to set it up. Clarification added in my answer.

Comment: The startup items shown in Task Manager are not necessarily in either the User or All Users startup folders. I have a half-dozen startup items in the T.M. Startup tab, and nothing in either startup folder (Windows 10 2004).

Comment: I didn't know it wouldn't show up in task manager, turns out all I had to do was create a startup folder, when I restarted my computer it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, as I posted in my solution, you can add items manually to the ProgramData ... Startup and then items will start on computer restart. So that is as I posted above.

Comment: @anoor1234 - You might acknowledge my answer as everything you needed to know (and that you used) are in my answer above. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to type `shell:startup` and not `shell.startup`, a colon, not a full-stop.

It should take you to the per-user startup folder at

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Alternatively you can get to the same location by going to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Additionally, `shell:common startup` will bring you to the startup folder which applies to all accounts.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just a typo, still though I tried that and it didn't work, I also just tried shell:common startup and it didn't work either.